# std::transform() passing reference in the function parameter

Tags: c++, algorithm, reference

My question/concern is about the function parameter to be used in `std::transform()`.

In the following codes, if I used a "pass-by-reference" in the integer parameter `i` of the squared function (i.e. `int squared(int i))`, it does not compile.

I have to change it to pass by value so that it compiles. Can anyone please tell me why and if this is a cosntraint for using `std::transform()`?

The `std::for_each()` is fine with using both "pass-by-value" and "pass-by-reference" approaches (as shown in `print()`).

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int squared(int i);
void print(int &i);


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> intVec;
    std::vector<int> newIntVec;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        intVec.push_back(i);

    std::for_each(intVec.begin(), intVec.end(), print);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::transform(intVec.begin(), intVec.end(), std::back_inserter(newIntVec), squared);
    std::for_each(newIntVec.begin(), newIntVec.end(), print);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;

}

int squared(int i)
{
    return i*i;
}

void print(int &i)
{
    std::cout << i << "  ";
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't matter, and it [works for me.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6416cd90fdbf444d) What's the error you get?

Comment: In the second paragraph of your question you talk about pass-by-reference, i.e. `int squared(int)` ... but that doesn't pass by reference. Do you mean `int squared(int&)`?  **Please describe the specific problem and provide valid code to reproduce it.** The code you've provided compiles fine, and you haven't described any compilation error. Voting to close.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Yes the above codes compile correctly. If you change the prototype (and the definition) of the function to use a "pass-by-reference", you will then see the compilation error.

Comment: @Genius101, no I won't see it. I don't get an error when I change the code, and neither does jrok. Instead of showing code that works (which is useless and of no interest to anyone), show the code that you say doesn't work, and the error message you get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a `std::transform`, the operator should have no side-effects (it should take the input and provide an output).  So you should try making the reference const:

```
int squared(const int &i)
{
    return i*i;
}
```

To quote from [CPP Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform), "[the function] must not have side effects" (C++), and also "[the function] must not invalidate any iterators, including the end iterators, *or modify any elements of the ranges involved*." (C++11)

This basically means that what gets passed to your function should be considered immutable... hence if you pass by reference, it should be a const reference.

Conversely, `std::for_each` operates on the series of data you pass it, meaning that the values can be modified.

Comment: This explains why the semantics suggest you use `const int &i` but it doesn't explain why it's a compiler error if you use `int &i`. Also, the two quotes you provide from a site calling itself CPP reference actually refer to two different versions of the C++ standard (as the site itself notes). (Clearly the first, older restriction implies the second, current one, but it was too restrictive.)

Comment: @rici: indeed, I tried the OP's code on a couple compilers, and it seemed to work, but figured the "no side-effects" was worth mentioning. As for the two quotes referring to different versions of C++, that's true, but it's not clear which version the OP is using. I'll update the answer a little.